# Populate Combobox from outcome of other combobox in Acrobat

Tags: javascript, combobox, adobe, acrobat

I am trying to have the setItems of combobox1 dependent on the selection a user makes in combobox2.
I have a script that achieves this but the field keeps resetting.

```
    if (combobox2.value==1)
{combobox1.setItems( [["a", "1"],["b", "2"]]);}
else if (combobox2.value==2)
{combobox1.setItems( ["e","1"]);}
```

I have tried placing this on several different fields with no change. My ultimate goal is to have a combobox that changes the setItems on the target combobox and its many export values will work into another script.

I figure the problem is that it has to reference the export value which is constant so the setItems continuously refreshes. I need a way to dynamically setItems while still using comboboxes. I know I could use a mouse up action but that doesn't work with combobox's export value.
Any help is always appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution posted on another forum. For anyone else looking, the solution is to use a validation script on the first combobox.

```
switch (event.value) {

case "Example1"://uservalue of combobox1

    this.getField("Combobox2").setItems( [["a", "1"],["b", "2"]]);

    break;

case "Example2"://uservalue of combobox1

    this.getField("Combobox2").setItems( ["e","1"]);

    break;
```

}